# Algorithm for generating homeomorphically irreducible trees of size n

Tags: algorithms, trees

In [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iW_LkYiuTKE) they talk about generating all the homeomorphically irreducible trees of size 10.

I was wondering if there is a generating algorithm for generating all the homeomorphically irreducible trees of size n? by generating algorithm I do not mean one that generates all possible trees and then tests and removes the undesired ones, but one that generates one after the other, or by some transformation of a acceptable tree to a new acceptable tree.